# Seeking details relating to Amiga 3000 serial numbers

Tags: amiga, amiga-3000

I am the original owner of my Amiga 3000.  As I remember it, I purchased the machine fairly early after release.  I'm cleaning and detailing the machine, and I took a quick picture of the serial number sticker on the mainboard.

[image: Image of sticker]

Obviously this indicates the board is an A3000, serial number 7779.  But I'm not sure what the N signifies, and assuming they started at the number 1, I would have to guess this was the 7,779th machine built or assembled. Further, I would infer the 4/90 (with 91 scratched out) is a production, inspection, or ship date.

Can anyone tell me what the HKC or WW markings refer to?  Or offer any other interesting information (manufacturing location, etc) that could be determined from this serial number?

I did some googling but my google-fu is apparently weak.

As always, all responses are much appreciated!

**UPDATE 10/28/2018**

I have recently had an opportunity to look more closely at my A3000 mainboard.  I also did a review of some excellent images found on [www.bigbookofamigahardware.com](http://www.bigbookofamigahardware.com) and am convinced the answer by Brian H below is spot on.

After looking at the images I was able to find online that were clear enough to read I have noted the following:

- a REV 6.1 board from WW 3 (I think, it was difficult to read) with a SN of 00101
- a REV 7.0 board (nothing written on the WW sticker) with a SN of 00662
- a REV 7.2 board from WW 21 (again, difficult to read) with a SN of 00804
- a REV 8.9 board (nothing written on the WW sticker) with a SN of 02845
- my personal board is a REV 9/01 (from the silkscreen) from WW 41 with a SN of 07779 (shown above)

This *seems* to indicate the SN are simple counters going upward over time.

It might be interesting to collect the Rev, SN and WW from other owners to form a more concrete conclusion.

Comment: "HKC" is often used for "Hong Kong City" which, given Commodore's history, seems a legit guess.

Comment: I believe that's not 4/90, but 41/90 (meaning "week 41 of 1990")

Comment: Some other serial stickers have HKM on them, not sure what either means.

Comment: Joe, week 41 of 1990 sounds like a very good interpretation.  According to wikipedia the A3000 was released in June 1990, so it tracks that I would have purchased it later that year.  Week 41 would have been early October of 1990.  Good eye!

Comment: WW=work week. Also look for an [barcode](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/249/what-information-is-encoded-in-amigas-22-digit-barcodes) on the outside of the chassis. AFAIK, Amiga 3000s were built in the USA, Germany, and Hong Kong.

Comment: traal, thanks.  work week tracks nicely with Joe's comment.

Comment: Note that sometimes the first serial number is neither "00001" nor "00000".  The manufacturer could start their sequence at 1000 or even 5000.  It is possible the serial numbers are not even sequential but just some unique identifier used at the factory. An example for 07779 might be, "mother board rev 0, factory #7, 779th unit". Or, you could actually have the 7,779th Amiga 3000 motherboard.

Comment: The 'N' could be NTSC?; it's common in the semiconductor industry to put the week as the batch number; it's not an Amiga thing, it's on tons of devices.

Comment: Photographs of other stickers might help. I have found one [here](//www.amibay.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=56783&d=1386607280), but it requires an amibay.com account to view (except when `&thumb=1` is added to it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Amiga 3000 was offered in 4 configurations: 25MHz NTSC, 25MHz PAL, 16MHz NTSC, 16 MHz PAL. Besides the ID of "A3000 N" which appears on your A3000, the other possible ID is "A3000 P". It might be considered an obvious conclusion that the "N" refers to NTSC and the "P" refers to PAL configurations. However, I think that requires some more explanation.

The only difference between NTSC & PAL for an A3000 is a jumper setting (J200). That seems like a relatively minor configuration setting to base your component labeling off of. Especially, given that the distinction between the 25MHz and the 16MHz configurations included not only many jumpers, but many expensive components soldered to the board (like 25MHz vs. 16MHz rated CPU and FPU).

Because of the above, I don't think the marking of "N" for NTSC and "P" for PAL was so much about the board configuration. Rather, it was intended to sort the systems heading West from Hong Kong (Europe) from those heading East from Hong Kong (California). So the "N"-marked boards should primarily originate from North America, while the "P" boards ought to primarily originate from European markets. I am over-simplifying, given that some A3000's might have shipped to non-European PAL regions. Sorting at the factory was probably based on destination country, not just my simplified East/West dichotomy.

As far as "HKC" on the sticker, it refers to "Hong Kong City". On most A3000 motherboards, and also the daughterboards, you can also locate a separate sticker that reads "QC Assembled in Hong Kong PASS". This is a secondary confirmation of the location of assembly for the boards. Incidentally, the S/N sticker on the A3000 Daughterboard is the identical format to the motherboard S/N sticker, but uses "DAUGHTER" ID instead of the "N" or "P".

For the date of assembly, it is coded with the handwritten week of the year following the "WW", and crossing out of the non-applicaple year. So, your example was assembled week 41 of 1990; pretty early in the A3000's life.

Comment: NTSC and PAL machines also used different chipset clock oscillators - 28.6363 MHz for NTSC and 28.375 MHz for PAL.