# How many Amiga 3000's were produced?

Tags: history, amiga, commodore, amiga-3000

While revisiting this question: [Seeking details relating to Amiga 3000 serial numbers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/seeking-details-relating-to-amiga-3000-serial-numbers) I began to wonder how many actual Amiga 3000's were produced by Commodore.

I suspect (like most production numbers) this isn't easily answered, and is probably further complicated by various configurations (16/25Mhz) and additional models like the A3000T and A3000UX.

Does anyone have any actual data, estimates, or wild guesses?

Comment: You may be able to use the German Tank method to find this out.

Comment: Here are some (incomplete) sales figures: http://www.amigahistory.plus.com/sales.html

Comment: @traal, thanks for that link.  I guess if we accept their assertion that 1993 global Amiga sales were in the neighborhood of 4.5 million Amiga's (all models) with Germany representing 31% of that total at 1.4 million, we can reverse-extrapolate that the 8,300 Amiga 3000's sold in Germany represent 31% of the total A3000's sold, yielding a total of about 27,000 A3000's sold worldwide.  I suspect this math is complete bollocks. :-)

Comment: @Wilson, I also tried your suggestion using the German Tank, but my supply of known serials is rather small.  The largest I have found (so far) is only 08820 from here: http://www.teemuntaksi.fi/MyComputers/A3000.html - If n = m + m/k -1 then n = 8820 + 8820/5 -1 = 10,582.  Again, this feels like complete bollocks (but even so, a really good idea on your part).

Comment: @Geo... That's just from one factory, probably Germany. Amiga 3000 motherboards were made in at least 3 factories including the USA and Hong Kong, and AFAIK they each had their own serial numbering.